# 80s or 90s Sci-fi book series featuring extravagant alien with proboscis and sting

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a sci-fi book series (2 or 3 books), that I unfortunately don't remember much about:

- funny
- human protagonist with alien sidekick
- underdog story type
- alien sidekick features a proboscis (100% sure about that, I had to look the word up ;-) ) and a sting
- alien sidekick vaguely of caterpillar shape (that just might be head canon ;-) )
- English language

I read the books in the mid 90s, so I guess the books were most probably  published in the late 80s to early 90s. The author had already died by the time I read them. I borrowed the books from a college friend. This being the pre-Amazon age, the books couldn't have been too arcane for him to be able to buy them in Austria.

Does that ring a bell? I'd really love to reread those.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site, including tips on story identification questions.

Comment: Do you remember if everyone involved happened to be doctors at a space-station hospital, for instance?  Because "human protagonist, insect-like secondary character, caterpillar-like other character (a nurse)" all ring a bell on the Sector General series.  Can't remember specifically if Dr. Prilicla had a proboscis or sting though.

Comment: No, definitely not centered on a hospital, but sector general sounds very interesting. I'll pick up one of those for sure :-) There were not that many books in the series, because once amazon was around and the internet really took off, I tried to get some more books of the series only to find out there were no more books and the author had already died.